# Indentation in programmatically created XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XmlWriter as follows

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
using (XmlWriter currentWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{
    workingXmlDocument.WriteTo(currentWriter);
    currentWriter.Flush();
} // using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath))
```

I have programmatically created an Xml Document that I am trying to write with this, and it is writting just fine, except that I have a block of elements that are created in a loop and it is putting all these elements onto one line.  If you need to see any other code from the program let me know and I can put it here. I welcome any ideas even if they aren't full solutions.

**Update - the complete method where the problem is happening**

```
private void XMLReaderUtil(string filePath)
    {
        XDocument workingXmlDocument;

        using (XmlReader currentReader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {

            workingXmlDocument = XDocument.Load(currentReader);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> currentIteration in logDataRaw)
            {
                FileInfo currentEntry = new FileInfo(currentIteration.Value);

                string testString = currentEntry.Directory.Name;

                if (testString.Contains(" ")) { testString = testString.Replace(" ", "_"); }

                IEnumerable<XElement> list = from XElement e in workingXmlDocument.Descendants(wixNS + testString)
                                             select e;

                DirectoryInfo temp = currentEntry.Directory;

                while (list.Count() == 0 && !temp.Name.Contains(":"))
                {
                    testString = temp.Name;

                    if (testString.Contains(" ")) { testString = testString.Replace(" ", "_"); }

                    list = from XElement e in workingXmlDocument.Descendants(wixNS + testString)
                           select e;
                    temp = temp.Parent;
                } // while (list.Count() == 0 && !temp.Name.Contains(":"))

                if (list.Count() == 0)
                {
                    IEnumerable<XElement> targetDirectory =
                        from XElement e in workingXmlDocument.Descendants(wixNS + "Directory")
                        where e.Attribute("Id").Value == "TARGETDIR"
                        select e;

                    var outXml = new XElement("root");
                    foreach (var item in targetDirectory)
                    {
                        item.Add(new XElement(
                             "Directory",
                             new XAttribute("new", 1)));

                        outXml.Add(item);
                    }

                    outXml.Save(@"c:\users\adkins\desktop\temp.wxs", SaveOptions.None);

                }
            } // foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in xmlDataChanged)
            // return workingXmlDocument;
        } // using (XmlReader sr = XmlReader.Create(FilePath))

        IEnumerable<XElement> cleanup =
            from XElement e in workingXmlDocument.Descendants(wixNS + "Directory")
            select e;
        Collection<string> keep = new Collection<string>();
        XElement[] blah;
        blah = cleanup.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < blah.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!keep.Contains(blah[i].Attribute("Id").Value))
            {
                keep.Add(blah[i].Attribute("Id").Value);
            }
            else
            {
                blah[i].Remove();
            }
        }

        workingXmlDocument.Save(filePath, SaveOptions.None);

        // XMLWriter attempt
        //XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        //settings.Indent = true;
        //settings.IndentChars = "\t";
        //settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
        //settings.NewLineChars = "\n";
        //settings.CloseOutput = true;
        //settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //using (XmlWriter currentWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
        //{
        //    workingXmlDocument.WriteTo(currentWriter);
        //    currentWriter.Flush();
        //} // using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath))

        //TextWriter test run - nothing changed
        //XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        //writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        //writer.IndentChar = '\t';
        //writer.Indentation = 1;

        //workingXmlDocument.WriteTo(writer);
        //writer.Flush();
        //writer.Close();

    }
```

Here is the complete problem method.  It includes my attempts at various forms of saving the file.  It is a complete mess due to my efforts to solve this problem and problems that I encountered before getting to this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The variable "logDataRaw" is a dictionary containing the name of a file and the path to where it is stored.  If you need any other clarification please let me know.

Comment: Aside: You should make sure you set `XmlWriterSettings.CloseOutput` to `true` so that when the writer is disposed, it closes the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was loading the XML file through an XMLReader.  Once I removed that and just loaded it directly into my XDocument than everything worked fine.

Comment: How strange it is! I got the same problem and you're right... I can't believe it that the XmlReader affects XmlWriter...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use XElement.Save() instead of XmlWriter?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538458.aspx

EDIT:

I just ran the following bit of code

```
        var xml = new XElement("root",
                               new XElement("node",
                                            new XAttribute("index", 1)
                                ),
                               new XElement("node",
                                            new XAttribute("index", 2)
                                ),
                               new XElement("node",
                                            new XAttribute("index", 3)
                                ),
                               new XElement("node",
                                            new XAttribute("index", 4)
                                )
            );

        IEnumerable<XElement> ieXml =
            from XElement e in xml.Elements()
            select e;

        var outXml = new XElement("root");
        foreach (var item in ieXml)
        {
            item.Add(new XElement(
                 "Directory",
                 new XAttribute("new", 1)));

            outXml.Add(item);
        }


        outXml.Save(@"d:\foo.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

and the result is formatted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node index="1">
    <Directory new="1" />
  </node>
  <node index="2">
    <Directory new="1" />
  </node>
  <node index="3">
    <Directory new="1" />
  </node>
  <node index="4">
    <Directory new="1" />
  </node>
</root>
```

I don't know what you're doing differently, but this works.

Comment: @Chad: I believe the OP wants to serialize the entire document, not just an element. So, might I suggest you recomment `XDocument.Save()` instead. Though I suspect that just uses `XmlWriter` under the hood.

Comment: @Chad: I tried that with XDocument instead of XElement, but got the same output.

Comment: @Jeff, what are the save options you are using?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx
As it should keep it

Comment: @Chad: XElement.Save uses XmlWriter under the hood so it doesn't fix the problem. You can look at this yourself using .NET Reflector.

Comment: @Chad: I have some XML code that was created the same way and is formatted perfectly, but if you look at the second code block that I pasted, that is the one causing a problem.  When I add elements in the middle through the use of a loop they are all staying on the same line.

Comment: Yes: Just use (XElement/XDocument).Save. Don't even import System.XML :D

Comment: @Chad: While it *should* work. It doesn't. Hence the OPs question. Using XmlWriter directly or via the Save method doesn't make much difference. It doesn't work in this particular scenario either way.

Comment: @Jeff, rather than criticizing my responses, you could attempt to be useful and look for a solution... as criticizing me, doesn't help Adkins at all

Comment: @Adkins, I changed the code again, to be more similar to what you are doing.  The key difference is in your foreach loop, add the "now" variable to an XElement (or XDocument) and save that.  I don't understand why you're using an IEnumerable of XElements instead of an XElement with child XElements

Comment: @Chad: I'm  sorry. I wasn't criticizing you, personally. I was merely responding to your points and highlighting that the call did the same thing. I have been helping Adkins (I even suggested he raise this question) and I was stuck. I'm sorry that you took it personally when I pointed out this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the entire method that is causing the problem. I have left in the XMLTextWriter attempt, and the XMLWriter attempt.  I am not sure where the problem is coming from.  Thank you so much for your continued help and thought into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to use an XmlTextWriter with default encoding instead of XmlWriter and set the Formatting property of the Writer object to Formatting.Indented

Comment: I have tried that. I updated my code to show what all I have tried for saving.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody uses XDocument and still has problems with saving XML to file with correct indent this might help you, it did for me:

1. In addition to Chad's answer I had to use XName.Get(...) when specifying XElement name:

   ```
   var xdoc = new XDocument(
               new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
               new XElement(XName.Get("TranslationContainer"),
                            new XElement(XName.Get("Translations"))));
   ```
2. Check that you have a well-formatted xml (don't have text outside xml tags)

Good luck.